# how to identify the color of a cell in excel to delete in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, office-interop, epplus

i have a question

I am playing with excel files in vb.net using epplus and interop as references.
Now I want to delete cells that are of a certain color.

for example the color is green, its rgb code is (0, 176, 80)
what function, library or reference i have to use to make that validation?

like this pseudocode

```
 if ((hoja1.cells("B"+ 1) is green)= true) then
    delete(cells) 
    end if
```

My cells look like this to fill it:

```
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
    Dim path As String = seleccionardirectorio("Excel|.xlsx")
    If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) = False) Then

        Dim excel = New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(path))
        excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Resultado")

     Dim aux As Integer = 1
     hoja1.Cells("B" & aux).Value = AREA.Item(aux - 1)
           While(aux <= AREA.Count)
                hoja1.Cells("B" & aux).Value = AREA.Item(aux - 1)
                    aux += 1
                End While
                aux = 1
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    If Range("C3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
        Range("C3").Clear
    End If
```

You can use Range("C3").Delete but it will shift other cells

Comment: yeah, i tried that but for some reason it doesnt recognize .interior.color, maybe because to generate the excel i am using epplus methods?, i updated my question with more code